# Are functions written in other languages subject to the rules of C++ regarding UB?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, language-lawyer

This question might make no sense, but I'll ask anyway with an example. Does this code exhibit undefined behaviour?

```
int main() {
    int a, b; // uninitialised

    memcpy(&a, &b, sizeof(int));
}
```

I would usually say yes, because causing an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion of an uninitialised object is UB, something which must be done to copy the bytes of `b` to `a`.

However, `memcpy` may or may not be implemented in C++. If `memcpy` is written in assembly for example, then there are no such rules. Do programs that do things that would normally cause undefined behaviour still cause it if they outsource the offending operations to other languages with dissimilar rules?

Comment: P.S: If someone knows whether and why `&b` is implied to be UB by 4.1/1, then he may want to answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14730534/dangling-references-and-undefined-behavior) too.

Comment: @AndyProwl it's not (and that's a different question; this isn't a dangling reference).

Comment: I thought you were implying that by saying "causing an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion of an uninitialised object is UB"

Comment: @AndyProwl taking the address of an object doesn't convert it to an rvalue, right(?)

Comment: I thought so, but today I've been reading too much Standardese trying to figure out the answer to the question I linked, and now even common-sense stuff is no more common-sense to me

Comment: I think the idea is, you can't write `memcpy` in C or C++ without using a lvalue-to-rvalue conversion of the bytes `((char*)&b)[i]`.

Comment: By the way, what does the C Standard require as preconditions to `memcpy`?

Comment: @aschepler good question, but this question doesn't apply only to `memcpy`, so it doesn't really matter if it requires initialised objects or something.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: I disagree. If you write a function of your own, you are responsible for documenting its capabilties and requirements, in which case, sure, assembly might do something not strictly possible in C++. But C++ defines the behavior of `memcpy` by deferring to the C Standard, and that definition might not necessarily imply that any lvalue-to-rvalue conversions actually happen.

Comment: @aschepler I'm talking strictly about undefined behaviour, not "desired behaviour". And if using `memcpy` thus is undefined just because of a requirement of the standard, then I'll just pick another function that I wrote or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is sort of like asking, "In C++, does excessively charring a steak cause Undefined Behavior?"

All Undefined Behavior means is that the C++ (or C, etc.) Standard does not guarantee what will happen when translating and/or executing a program.  Not surprisingly, the C++ Standard doesn't say much at all about functions from other languages.

The only somewhat relevant quotes are from 7.4

> The `asm` declaration is conditionally-supported; its meaning is implementation-defined.

and from 7.5

> [In a *linkage-specification* syntax...]  This International Standard specifies the semantics for the *string-literals* `"C"` and `"C++"`.  Use of a *string-literal* other than `"C"` or `"C++"` is conditionally-supported, with implementation-defined semantics.

So basically, it might be possible to use other languages along with C++, but this document isn't going to talk about that other than the syntax necessary to glue the pieces together.

From the point of view of the C++ Standard, functions from other languages have implementation-defined effects on C++ programs.  Implementation-Defined is usually considered better than Undefined Behavior, though unportable.  But it shouldn't be a surprise that using something other than C++ and C is not necessarily portable to every C++ implementation.

Answer (score 2):

In the case you describe `a` is allocated by the C++ program and passed to `memcpy()`. That means that the behavior is still undefined.

However, this does not mean that the behavior will be random or change between runs. Undefined means that the behavior is not defined. That means that you cannot rely on any particular behavior, including the program breaking. Some of the hardest problems to debug in C or C++ is when the compiler translates an undefined construct into something which works as expected. Then suddenly things stop working when you change a compiler flag.

Comment: What part of the standard are you using for this conclusion?

Answer (score 1):

UB is not a language specific "thing". It is "what you are doing doesn't have a defined behaviour". So the reason that "using uninitialized memory is undefined" is that the language C can not stipulate what should happen if you read memory that hasn't been written to. As discussed in another answer, if the memory is not initialized, it may have parity or ECC errors, because the parity bit is set correctly on the first write. When memory contains "whatever it came out of power-up as", it may well have the wrong parity/ecc value.

ECC or parity errors often lead to the system stopping, because it's not expected to have bad memory!

So, it's not what language the code you execute is written in that matters, it is "the behaviour if you read from memory that hasn't been initialized could go wrong". The act of reading the memory, whether the code is written in C, C++, assembler, Pascal, Fortran or LisP.

And bear in mind that undefined isn't necessarily that "Bad things happen", just that "the specification does not explain what the result is, and bad things are allowed to happen in UB". Dividing by zero is not guaranteed to crash your program - it most likely will, but it may also just give you back the same value as you fed in on the other side of the `/` - that would be perfectly valid UB. Reading uninitialized memory  can result in "you get zero", or "you get all ones", or "you get some mixture of ones and zeros, nobody knows which ones", or "could lead to the system rebooting due to suspected memory error". And of course, it may not be the same every time either - sometimes the parity bits are "right", sometimes not, for example.

To clarify: I'm not one of those people that know every paragraph of every section of the C or C++ standards. I write code for a living, and I know enough of how processors and connected hardware to understand WHY the specifications say "it is undefined behaviour when you ..." [it probably doesn't use those words at all, since standards don't use second person] - in the case of using variables that haven't been initialized, the C language doesn't try to enforce any particular behaviour, because it MAY restrict the language from being used on a particular platform, because the platform can't guarantee that behaviour [and if you specify a behaviour, someone will rely on that behaviour sooner or later, making it a necessary part to implement on every platform].

Comment: I don't think the standard doesn't say anything about reading uninitialised memory. If you have a reference it would be good.

Comment: By uninitialized memory, I mean variables that haven't been set to anything, such as `b` in the case above. Since we take the address of `b`, it cane be allocated into a register, so it must be in 'memory' somewhere, right?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the C/C++ standards don't really deal with "memory" as such anywhere - it doesn't even say stack, if I've not misunderstood things.

Comment: Yes, but the standard doesn't say that reading uninitialised memory is undefined. What makes things like `int a; cout << a` undefined is the conversion of `a` from an lvalue to an rvalue, so talking about memory doesn't help.

Comment: So, how would you explain an ECC / Parity error caused by calling `memcpy()` above? [I used to work with systems that have ECC or parity, and we would run into these sort of problems when some programmer was trying to be clever and not initialize certain types of structures!]

Answer (score 1):

An implementation is free to extend the language and gives a defined behavior to a C undefined  behavior. In the example of reading an uninitialized object with automatic storage duration (UB in C) it can say its value is unspecified but that evaluating the object does not invoke undefined behavior.

In the C89 and C99 Rationales, C committee says that:

> Undefined behavior gives the implementor license not to catch certain program errors that are difficult to diagnose. It also identifies areas of possible conforming language extension: **the implementor may augment the language by providing a definition of the officially undefined behavior**.*

Such a program will be a valid program for this implementation but will still be an invalid C program.

Comment: I don't understand how that means that a program in another language can give a C++ one undefined behaviour.

Comment: My answer is for C (I didn't notice the C++ tag), but the definition of undefined behavior in C and C++ is similar. C and C++ behaviors are described in terms of an abstract machine. A C++ program that invokes undefined behavior is not a C++ program (it is an erroneous C++ program) but a C++ implementation can relax the rules by extending the language and defining an undefined behavior.

Comment: I think that doesn't really clear anything up for me. I'm not asking what undefined behaviour is. I'm asking whether or not a C++ program has UB if it calls a function that is written in some other language that does something that couldn't be done in C++ without UB.

Answer (score 0):

This refers to `http://blog.regehr.org/archives/213` which I suggest.  If you want to argue about the following defintions, please take it up over there. IMO, this is the heart of what you are asking and most answers are trying to convey.  You are free to disagree.

Let's consider #1 and #2 of these:

```
Type 1: Behavior is defined for all inputs 
Type 2: Behavior is defined for some inputs and undefined for others 
Type 3: Behavior is undefined for all inputs
```

Type 1 means the function raises errors and exceptions to prevent going into UB.
Type 2 means the code does not raise all possible error and exceptions and may possibly go into UB.

The point is: you are using a documented library call.   Let's use the example of strcpy or gets instead.  It seems to be common knowledge that you can feed these library calls long strings and overflow memory, causing UB.  There are implementation-defined constraints that may stop this but you know better.   So, your question really has little to wrt the standard but everything about what the documentation for the library call says, and whether it is a Type 1 or Type 2.  strcpy, gets, and other library functions may clearly be Type 2.  So it is a caveat to the users of the library.  I am Type 2, I may explode when provoked.

IMO, there is no way a standard can deal with library add-ons, because they are implementation-defined. So the answer is: it has nothing to do with C++ standards.