# Adding objects into vector inside map

Tags: c++, containers

```
class Obj {
    private:
        const string & m_String;
    public:
        Obj ( const string & x )
          : m_String ( x ) {}
        ... // getters, overloaded operators etc
};

int main ( void ) {
    // new map
    map<string, vector<Obj>> myMap;
    myMap . insert ( pair<string, vector<Obj>> ("1st", vector<Obj>() ) );

    Obj a1 ("a"), a2 ("b");

    // add three elements into "1st"
    myMap["1st"] . push_back (a1);
    myMap["1st"] . push_back (a2);
    myMap["1st"] . push_back (a2);

    // display contents of all vecs inside map
    for ( map<string, vector<Obj>>::const_iterator it1 = myMap . begin(); it1 != myMap . end(); ++it1 ) {
        cout << it1 -> first << ":"<< endl;
        for ( vector<Obj>::const_iterator it2 = it1->second . begin(); it2 != it1->second . end(); ++it2) {
            cout << *it2;
            if ( it2 != prev(it1->second . end()) ) cout << ", ";
            else cout << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to push back some objects into a vector inside a map. The code compiles with no warnings
but the output is

```
1st:
a, 1st, 1st
```

instead of the desired output

```
1st:
a, b, b
```

Can't figure out a legit reason why. The vector works fine with ints, strings etc. and it should work with objects, but for some reason it doesn't. Tried using pointers of objects aswell to no avail.
regards

Comment: You've redacted the most important part, that is `Obj`'s constructor, but since there's no sane way `Obj a1 ("a");` would end up referring to a valid `std::string` I'd bet on `m_String` being a dangling reference every time.

Comment: Why do you need a string reference as a member?  Why not simply `std::string m_String`?  We could be heading into [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) territory.

Comment: There's something in your `Obj` class, because simple replacing it with `std::string` leads to correct behaviour: https://godbolt.org/z/Ja4QxJ I think the problem is - you have somewhere a dangling reference - your `Obj`'s member is a reference and probably you assign a temporary string to it (for example here: `Obj a1 ("a"), a2 ("b");`). You may have some black magic in your constructor, but I don't think so :) UPD: The constructor appeared now and my hypothesis was right

Comment: Thanks for the replies, changing it to normal string works!

Answer (score 3):

Your bug is using a reference to string in your `Obj` object.

Your code is building `Obj`'s using temporary strings and then storing references to them. That's undefined behavior, and whatever your reference ends up pointing to could be anything.

Comment: using the references is undefined. Having references dangling alone is no problem

Comment: @idclev463035818 I'd have to double-check but I am pretty sure that unlike pointers, even creating invalid references is technically undefined. By the language rules, references should always be valid.

Comment: I have to admit that I am not completely certain. I'll do some research

Comment: @idclev463035818 some good stuff here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14730534/dangling-references-and-undefined-behavior

Comment: @idclev463035818 I am thinking now that creating an invalid reference is always wrong, but having one that used to be valid and fell out of scope, i.e. dangling, is only wrong if you use it, as you said.

Comment: I believe so, otherwise such innocent looking code would be UB `int* x = new int(0);int& y = *x;delete x;`. Of course that is no convincing argument, but I will have to do more reading to convince myself. Btw I had a fruitless debate about references recently, thats why I care about it, otherwise I would not have jumped on such detail in a good answer.