# Reference list element then popping it, is it undefined behaviour?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior

I have this piece of code and I wonder if it is valid or can cause undefined behaviour:

```cpp
#include <list>
#include <utility>

void myFunction(std::list<std::pair<int, int>> foo)
{
    while (foo.size())
    {
        std::pair<int, int> const &bar = foo.front();

        //work with bar

        foo.pop_front();
    }
}
```

I am using a reference to avoid duplicating the already existing pair.

On one side, I think this could be an undefined behaviour because I am removing a referenced element but, on the other side, I am not accessing the reference after removing it.

Is it valid?

Comment: If you don't use `bar` after popping it, this is fine.

Comment: I don't know what is the exact wording in the standard but in practice it should work. Although, I would add `{}` around `std::pair<int, int> const &bar = foo.front(); //work with bar`, just to be sure.

Comment: Answers here seem to vaguely suggest that you're fine until you try to use the reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14730534/dangling-references-and-undefined-behavior

Comment: `while (foo.size())` -- Using `empty()` is more intuitive:  `while (!foo.empty())`

Comment: ... or `while (foo.size() != 0)`

Comment: A smart compiler might optimize the copy away if you're just doing `std::pair<int, int> const bar = foo.pop_front();`

Comment: If `//work with bar` implies changing `bar`, make it a non-`const` reference. It'd still be perfectly ok.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So long as you don't attempt to use the `bar` reference *after* the `foo.pop_front();` statement, then you won't get undefined behaviour, because that reference remains valid until the referred-to element is removed from the container.

In your case, the pop appears to be the very last statement in the scope of the reference (a new one will be created/formed on each iteration of the `while` loop), so that doesn't appear to be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks valid to me.
`std::list::pop_front()` decrements the `size`.
`std::list::empty()` returns true when the `begin` and `end` iterators compare equal. Size is 0 when the distance from begin to end is 0.
It's all well-defined behavior, as far as I know.